# Раскрывающееся подменю. Автоматическое закрытие раскрытых пунктов, при открытии новых

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть меню раскрывающееся:

```js
$(".nav-item-toggle > a").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).next().slideUp("easeOutExpo");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(this).next(".nav-item-submenu");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).next().slideDown("easeOutExpo");
  }

});
```

```css
.nav-item-submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item-toggle">
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  <div class="nav-item-submenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item-toggle">
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  <div class="nav-item-submenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item-toggle">
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  <div class="nav-item-submenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

При клике меню раскрывается, при повторном клике закрывается. Если оставить открытым одно подменю и раскрыть другое, то первое меню остается раскрытым. А хотелось бы, чтобы при раскрытии следующего подменю, предыдущие (ранее открытые) закрывались. Скилла мало, как сделать, подскажите люди добрые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед раскрытие подменю (на которое кликнули) просто скрывайте все остальные пункты:

```js
$(".nav-item-toggle > a").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).next().slideUp("easeOutExpo");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".nav-item-toggle > a").removeClass('active');
    $('.nav-item-submenu').slideUp("easeOutExpo");
    $(this).next(".nav-item-submenu");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).next().slideDown("easeOutExpo");
  }
});
```

```css
.nav-item-submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item-toggle">
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  <div class="nav-item-submenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item-toggle">
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  <div class="nav-item-submenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item-toggle">
  <a href="#">Ссылка</a>
  <div class="nav-item-submenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Супер!
Но теперь повторный клик на открытом пункте не закрывает его. Раскрытый пункт не возможно закрыть)))

Comment: @СергейМиронов поправил

Comment: Исренне благодарен!